# Effect of min_granularity_ns on performance

Tags: c, performance, x86-64, scheduler, perf

In order to find the effect of kernel parameter, `min_granularity_ns`, a 16-thread OMP implementation of a matrix multiplication [code](https://pastebin.com/JwXAP6hi) is launched with high and low values of that parameter. The perf result is shown below:

```
# echo 1000000 > /sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns
# perf stat -a -e $EVENTS -- ./mm_omp 16
Using 16 threads
Total execution Time in seconds: 12.3690895601
MM execution Time in seconds: 12.2312941169

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

            911.97 Joules power/energy-pkg/
   218,012,129,383        instructions              #    0.26  insn per cycle
   823,773,717,094        cycles
            37,701        context-switches
               131        cpu-migrations
            51,012        page-faults

      12.369310043 seconds time elapsed

# echo 1000000000 > /sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns
# perf stat -a -e $EVENTS -- ./mm_double_omp 16
Using 16 threads
Total execution Time in seconds: 12.3981724780
MM execution Time in seconds: 12.2612874920

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

            881.48 Joules power/energy-pkg/
   218,063,319,724        instructions              #    0.27  insn per cycle
   822,622,830,036        cycles
            37,959        context-switches
               146        cpu-migrations
            51,553        page-faults

      12.400958939 seconds time elapsed
```

As you can see there is no difference between the results albeit the large change in the kernel parameter, from 1 us to 1 second. Although there are other parameters in addition to `min_granularity_ns`, does that "no-difference" make sense? Or maybe this is not a correct program to test?

---

**UPDATE 1:** I test another implementation which uses [CBLAS](https://pastebin.com/Mkn383G7) and it utilizes 16-threads. As you can see, for a large matrix size (20k), the IPC is 1.77 which is acceptable. Again, by varying the `min_granularity_ns`, there is no difference in time, although the number of context-swtiches decreases for large granularity.

```
# echo 1000000 > /sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns
# perf stat -a -e $EVENTS -- ./mm_blas
Total execution Time in seconds: 47.0226452020
MM execution Time in seconds: 37.1756865050

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

          3,106.80 Joules power/energy-pkg/
 3,943,151,227,404        instructions              #    1.77  insn per cycle
 2,230,425,316,645        cycles
           273,271        context-switches
               383        cpu-migrations
         2,360,017        page-faults

      47.272118708 seconds time elapsed

# echo 1000000000 > /sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns
# perf stat -a -e $EVENTS -- ./mm_blas
Total execution Time in seconds: 46.8930790700
MM execution Time in seconds: 37.0639640210

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

          3,080.33 Joules power/energy-pkg/
 3,924,979,103,204        instructions              #    1.77  insn per cycle
 2,223,571,579,672        cycles
           125,643        context-switches
               355        cpu-migrations
         2,358,432        page-faults

      47.148148344 seconds time elapsed
```

Still I wonder what is the effect of that parameter on the performance.

Comment: That's very low IPC; possibly out-of-order exec isn't helping too much, so frequently getting interrupted (which drains the out-of-order back-end) maybe isn't hurting as much as in code that's generally high throughput but needs OoO exec to see a good window of instructions.  Also maybe cache locality isn't good, which would explain the garbage IPC; a well-tuned matmul should be running 2 SIMD FMAs per physical core per cycle, plus loads and stores, so you're under 1/10th that.  With poor locality, having kernel code execute often and take up some cache footprint doesn't hurt as much.

Comment: Would you please see the updated post?

Comment: Ok, yeah that's maybe a better test.  Still only like 1 part in 100 perf difference.  Is this using SMT to run 2 threads per core?  If so that would hide a lot of the throughput loss, with the other thread "expanding" to fill the idle cycles left right after returning from an interrupt.  (Which is similar to a system call in terms of perf overhead: [FlexSC: Flexible System Call Scheduling with Exception-Less System Calls](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Soares.pdf) is a paper that has some measurements/simulations of lowered IPC *after* a system-call returns.)

Comment: Also [Characterizing the Branch Misprediction Penalty](https://users.elis.ugent.be/~leeckhou/papers/ispass06-eyerman.pdf) might be relevant for understanding OoO exec after stalls.

Comment: Yes. The processor has 8 cores and run 16 threads.  With respect to reduced context switches (273k to 125k), why the execution time is almost the same.?

Comment: Regarding the timings and the context switches, there is about 3-6 context-switchs/ms. AFAIK a context switch takes about few us to complete. This means few dozens of us per ms. However, not all threads are impacted by context switches. Assuming they are uniformly balanced between cores, the actual overhead on the wall clock time is divided by the number of cores (8). As a result, it is only few us of overhead per ms (ie. <1%) which is certainly less than the variation of execution time between two run (due to many other source of noise). This is why there is no visible impact on the timings.

Comment: Note that `sched_min_granularity_ns` is a minimum time. If there are no process to execution at the end of this time, the scheduler have no reason to make a context switch. I expect a visible difference in the number of context-switches only if there are other applications running requesting some CPU time during the execution of your program. Besides this, I think `sched_min_granularity_ns` cannot be too big and the scheduler wait for many pending tasks; see the [Linux kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.34/source/kernel/sched_fair.c#L447).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: What you say make sense. As another try, I want to try with `stress --cpu 10 --io 8 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 512M --timeout 600s`, so the system has enough threads for 600 seconds. On another terminal, I want to run `perf -a -e $EVENTS -- sleep 5`. With different number of kernel parameters, do you agree that in some cases, the elapsed time for `sleep 5` should be larger than 5 seconds?